# What is the proper way of deploying versioned applications with docker?

Tags: playframework, docker

I have a play framework 2.3 application that I'd like to deploy (and keep updating) via docker. If I release a new version of the application, should I build a new docker image every time or build a single docker image that downloads and installs my application via git pull/apt-get?

The Dockerfiles I have seen so far install applications via apt-get (e.g. postgres image) which would mean to deploy a new version of my application I would just have to restart the container which would pull the latest release from a private .deb repository. Rolling back will be a nuisance because I would have to rush to create a new docker to point to a specific package version.

The alternative is to create a new image for each application version. However is that the "right" way to use docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build a new docker image every time and use the version part of the tag (e.g. `:latest` and `:2.3`) to help users pick the right one:

```
$ docker build -t pavel987/playframework:2.3 .
....
# docker builds
$ docker tag pavel987/playframework:2.3 pavel987/playframework:latest
# Assuming your Docker Hub user name is pavel987
$ docker push pavel987/playframework
```

Tagging with the version number and with `latest` lets your users automatically use the newest version (because the CLI will default to use `latest`) and still lets them pick a consistent version if they don't want things to change (e.g. `:2.3`). So in their own Dockerfiles they could use `FROM pavel987/playframework:latest` if they want to use the latest version, or `FROM pavel987/playframework:2.3` if they want to pin their base.

This all assumes that you want your primary distribution to be as a Docker image.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I do not plan to distribute the framework itself, but rather an application that uses the framework. This image won't be used as a base for other images. At the extreme end of it we will have CI that builds images and pushes them to production multiple times daily. Given the clarification, is your answer the commonly accepted way of deploying my custom application using docker?

Comment: Then both techniques are common (apt-get in Dockerfile or base image). The base image technique is more Docker-like since it ensures an immutable base and reduces surprises. So I would suggest creating a base image for your Play framework and then use that in a `FROM` statement when building your own app. When you make small changes to your app, your users won't have to re-download that base image again.